# Can we use map function on object instead of list to do bulk DML

Tags: apex

Wanted to understand what is more efficient to do bulk insert/updates on records.

```
Opportunity opportunity = new Opportunity();
for(Id accountId : accountIds) {
  opportunity.put('Name', 'Opportunity ' + accountId);
  opportunity.put('AccountId', accountId);
  opportunity.put('StageName', 'Prospecting');
  opportunity.put('Amount', 0.0);
  opportunity.put('CloseDate', Date.Today().addDays(90));
}

insert opportunity;
```

OR

```
List<Opportunity> opportunities = new List<Opportunity>();
for(Id accountId : accountIds) {
  Opportunity opp = new Opportunity();
  opp.Name = 'Opportunity ' + accountId;
  opp.AccountId =  accountId;
  opp.StageName = 'Prospecting';
  opp.Amount = 0.0;
  opp.CloseDate = Date.Today().addDays(90);
  opportunities.add(opp);
}

insert opportunities;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither of these examples uses a `Map`. You can't perform DML on a `Map`, although if you have, say, a `Map<Id, sObject>` you can do `insert myMap.values();`

Your first example is entirely wrong. It will insert exactly one Opportunity with the `AccountId` set to the last `Id` in `accountIds`, which is not what you want.

The second example is correctly bulkified.

Comment: got it. I thought doing a opportunity.put('Name', 'Opportunity ' + accountId); will create multiple instance of opportunity records (Which salesforce handle internally) like how map object would work ex: Map<Id, Opportunity> oppMap = new Map<Id, Opportunity> ();
oppMap.put('0068c00000pPOILAA4', opp);
oppMap.put('0068c00000pPOILAA5', opp);
update oppMap.values();

It makes sense that in my example its creating 1 single instance and the values are getting overriden as we loop over Id records and only final value in the loop will be updated.